# How can I detect when my socket has lost its TCP connection and reconnect?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, networking, network-programming

My application has an issue where if it loses its connection, it blocks forever and the whole application needs to be restarted.

Code in question:

```
def run(encoder, port, channel):

    decoder_socket = socket.socket()
    decoder_socket.connect((decoder, port))
    decoder_fp = decoder_socket.makefile("r", 0)

    parser = xml.sax.make_parser(['xml.sax.IncrementalParser'])
    parser.setContentHandler(RftDecoder())

    while True:
        data = decoder_fp.readline().strip("\x00") 
        if not(data):
            raise socket.error("no data")

        LOG.info("%s" % data.strip())
        parser.feed(data)
```

If the connection is actively closed by the other side, the exception is raised as expected, no problems. However when the connection is dropped (e.g., if *Decoder* crashes, or if the cable is unplugged), then the decoder_fp.readline() call blocks indefinitely.

Strace doesn't show anything when this happens, it just continues sitting on a recv() call.

So my question is, how can I detect when the connection is lost as described, and reconnect?

Comment: Close the socket and create and connect a new one.

Comment: The problem is detecting that the connection is lost.  raise socket.error("no data") is never reached. decoder_fp.readline() seems to block indefinitely when the connection drops.

Comment: And no exceptions? Hard to believe. Can you set a read timeout?

Comment: You can't set a read timeout on makefile()'d sockets

Comment: Cutting out the sax parser bits, your code works fine for me. When I close the connection from the server side, I get the "no data" `socket.error` as expected.

Comment: I think the distinction is in closing the connection you send a TCP FIN or RST packet which is handled fine. The problem I am experiencing occurrs when the connection is lost and there is no FIN/RST packet to close the connection gracefully.

Comment: If I do an strace, nothing happens when the decoder crashes and the connection is dropped, it just continues sitting on a recv() call indefinitely.

Comment: I suspect the [`settimeout()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) is incorrect, and that what it should say is that the socket can't be in non-blocking mode. Otherwise `makefile()` would be basically useless.

Comment: From the doco: `Timeout mode internally sets the socket in non-blocking mode. The blocking and timeout modes are shared between file descriptors and socket objects that refer to the same network endpoint. A consequence of this is that file objects returned by the makefile() method must only be used when the socket is in blocking mode; in timeout or non-blocking mode file operations that cannot be completed immediately will fail.`

Comment: Then frankly they are idiots. They should implement it properly. There is no need for all that nonsense. The Berkely Sockets API, which they are building on top of, supports read timeouts in blocking mode directly.